# get error message from jquery's eventData object

Tags: javascript, jquery, onerror

I currently have a javascript error handler like this:

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line){ //stuff }};
```

But I would like to be able to use jquery to attach to onerror like so:

```
$(window).error(function(evtData){//stuff});
```

My question is, from jquery's eventData object, how can i get the error's message, url, and line number, as I did in the non-jquery function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From jQuery docs.

> Note: **A jQuery error event handler should not be attached to the
>   window object.** The browser fires the window's error event when a
>   script error occurs. However, the window error event receives
>   different arguments and has different return value requirements than
>   conventional event handlers. Use window.onerror instead.

Refernce: http://api.jquery.com/error/